# Check session is set, codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have a upload script which post upload lets the user edit the content title for a period of time. It sets the following in the ci_sessions user_data column in the db:

```
array (
  'user_data' => '',
  'edit' => 
  array (
    'image_id' => 'HF',
    'session_id' => '783c15b057bcd9c19d3fd82f367ee55d',
  ),
)
```

The problem is my session CHECK code can't find the session:

```
<?php if ($this->session->userdata('edit') !== FALSE) : ?> 
<?php echo '<!-- session found -->'; ?>
    <?php $session_info = $this->session->userdata('edit'); ?>
    <?php $ids_array = explode(",", $session_info['image_id']); ?>
    <?php foreach ($ids_array as $id): ?>
    <?php 
    if ($id == $alpha_id 
    && 
    $session_info['session_id'] == $this->session->userdata('session_id')) :
    ?>
```

The echo on line 2 of that block never gets outputted.
Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? thanks

heres my controller http://pastebin.com/aXeRn1VN

Comment: Can you post the content of `config.php`?

Comment: Here's config.php session info http://pastebin.com/A31nrC1b

Comment: Try printing all the data with `$this->session->all_userdata()`. It shows something?

Comment: @SérgioMichels that outputs http://pastebin.com/sRtRaRbB

Comment: Also note user_data is NOT blank in the db, but there is multiple sessions with the same ip in the db (if relevant), but different session_ids of course

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php if( $this->session->userdata('edit') ) : ?>
```

instead of

```
<?php if ($this->session->userdata('edit') !== FALSE) : ?>
```

Comment: then you should check what your session contains with $this->session->all_userdata();

Comment: when i ouput that it says user_data is blank, but when i check in the db it is not blank, it has all the info

Comment: FYI, there seems to be multiple sessions in the db with the same ip (if thats relevant)

Comment: 'user_data' => '' what does this line means? and you cannot understand the values in db as codeigniter sessions are stored in an encrypted form

Comment: that's just the content in the user_data col in the db, and yes it is readable not encrypted

Comment: May be i am wrong but codeigniter doesnot support arrays in session variables try storing your array indexes as seperate variables in session.

Comment: setting sess_match_useragent=false in config fixed it